# Cannot read repositories after update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

This morning my system gave me a security update that I installed.

Now I cannot read or update Repositories, either from Update Manager or Terminal with `sudo apt-get update`.

I am getting the following messages:

```
The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
Is package apt-transport-https installed!
```

I get a similar message in Synaptic Package Manager.

Can anyone shed some light on what's happened and can I recover from this?

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you to check if the package `apt-transport-https` is installed.

You can do that by either

```
dpkg -l | grep apt-transport-https
```

or

```
apt-cache policy apt-transport-https
```

Seems like you accidently removed it. If that is the case try to reinstall it via `apt`.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

or shorter

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your suggestion but I alrady tried it.  I get the following:                                                                                                admin@ubuntu_14:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
admin@ubuntu_14:~$        So the package appears to be missing and I cannot update the repositories to re-load it.  Is there some other way?

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your suggestion but I alrady tried it.  I get the following:                                                                                                admin@ubuntu_14:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
admin@ubuntu_14:~$        So the package appears to be missing and I cannot update the repositories to re-load it.  Is there some other way?

Comment: Well - you could for sure manually download the package and install it manually via dpkg in terminal or doubeclick on the .deb file. But thats a method i wouldn't recommend